# ASP.NET (using VB.NET for code behind) Frames issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, frames

I am using frames for my web application.
Description
(1)Left Frame with a list of buttons (clicking them opens a web page in the right frame)
(2)Right Frame, opens the web page passed by the left frame.

---

Problem: Button click works perfectly in Internet Explorer 8.0 on production machine, Windows XP, 32 bit.

Button click event doesn't open anything in the right frame, just remains as it is, in
Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer 9.0

---

**Intial code that loads the frames**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="frmMain.aspx.vb" Inherits="XYZ" smartNavigation="True"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"  http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <TITLE>frmMain</</TITLE>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
    <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
</head>
<frameset COLS="20%,80%">
    <frame name="frame1" src="frmbuttons.aspx">
    <frame name="frame2" src="frmbegin.aspx">
</frameset>
```

**Example code (for a button in left frame):**

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
Dim url As String = String.Empty
url = "test.aspx"
Dim frameScript As String = "<script language='javascript'>" & "window.parent.frames(1).location='" & url & "';</script>"

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "FrameScript", frameScript, False)
end sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error message (if any) do you see in the browser's console window? I don't think using parentheses to index into an array is valid JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  This code causes an error:

```
Dim frameScript As String = "window.parent.frames(1).location='" & url & "'"
```

The above line has an error in `window.parent.frames(1)` because of the parenthesis `()`; the correct solution to this problem would be:

This code is correct:

```
Dim frameScript As String = "window.parent.frames[1].location='" & url & "'"
```

VB.Net uses parenthesis for array index access, but Javascript uses square brackets. Once I changed to the correct syntax, the code worked fine in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Dim frameScript As String = "window.parent.frames(1).location='" & url & "'"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "FrameScript", frameScript, False)
```

In my experience with ScriptManager, I've never needed the  tags, and it's always worked in IE, chrome and FF.

Comment: The last parameter passed to [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) is `bool addScriptTags`. In this case, the parameter is `false`, so the `<script>` tags are necessary.

Comment: Hi all, I have tried these suggestions (verified it several times) but still the problem persists. I really appreciate the responses.Any other suggestions are welcome.